# Call anova on lme4.lmer output via RPy

Tags: python, r, rpy2, anova, lme4

I am trying to analyze the deviance of a set of linear models generated with lme4.lmer() via RPy. [This notebook here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/7396334/raw/20c7878456fea4c05e1889d566ab1e5b20bc90bb/nlme-aov) shows a full example with me importing my deps, loading my files, running my lme4.lmer() and failing to get anova to run on them.

For your convenience here is again a paste of the line that is failing and which I would like to see work.

```
compare = stats.anova(res[0], res[1], res[2])
    Error in Ops.data.frame(data, data[[1]]) : 
      list of length 3 not meaningful
    In addition: Warning message:
    In anova.merMod(<S4 object of class "lmerMod">, <S4 object of class "lmerMod">,  :
      failed to find unique model names, assigning generic names

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-47-fe0ffa3b55de> in <module>()
    ----> 1 compare = stats.anova(res[0], res[1], res[2])

    /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in __call__(self, args, **kwargs)
         84                 v = kwargs.pop(k)
         85                 kwargs[r_k] = v
    ---> 86         return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         33         for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
         34             new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v)
    ---> 35         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
         36         res = conversion.ri2py(res)
         37         return res

    RRuntimeError: Error in Ops.data.frame(data, data[[1]]) : 
      list of length 3 not meaningful
```

This code runs perfectly in R as:

```
> mydata = read.csv("http://chymera.eu/data/test/r_data.csv")
> library(lme4)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: Matrix
> lme1 = lme4.lmer(formula='RT~cat2 + (1|ID)', data=mydata, REML=FALSE)
Error: could not find function "lme4.lmer"
> lme1 = lmer(formula='RT~cat1 + (1|ID)', data=mydata, REML=FALSE)
> lme2 = lmer(formula='RT~cat2 + (1|ID)', data=mydata, REML=FALSE)
> anova(lme1,lme2)
> lme3 = lmer(formula='RT~cat2*cat1 + (1|ID)', data=mydata, REML=FALSE)
> stats::anova(lme1, lme2, lme3)
Data: mydata
Models:
lme1: RT ~ cat1 + (1 | ID)
lme2: RT ~ cat2 + (1 | ID)
lme3: RT ~ cat2 * cat1 + (1 | ID)
     Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
lme1  4 116.68 122.29 -54.342   108.68                             
lme2  4 149.59 155.19 -70.793   141.59  0.000      0          1    
lme3  6 117.19 125.59 -52.594   105.19 36.398      2  1.248e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Can you help me make it run in RPy as well?

Comment: This is going to be a little tricky to debug through so many layers.  Can you get Rpy to give you more tracing/debugging information from R (e.g. the results of `traceback()`?) I think that sending `options(error=recover)` to R might help ...  Does a two-model `anova` work via RPy?

Comment: yes, the 2 model anova does work. Also, I updated my paste to show 3 models. where would I pass options(error=recover)? As I said, I believe the problem lies with RPy not passing the list of inputs correctly... I tried to pass them as [res[0],res[1],res[2]], but that doesn't work either (R complains about not knowing how to deal with lists)

Comment: does fitting three models with `lm` and using `anova()` on them work via RPy? (i.e. is this an lme4-specific problem?)

Comment: yes, this seems to be lme4-specific. See [this notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/7396334/raw/b0340eed447834070409cb093c8e285e4ac8a48d/nlme-aov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in R `stats::anova()` is presumably inferring the model names from the unevaluated expressions in the function call. Here that is `lme1`, `'lme2`, and `lme3`.

Now consider rewriting your R code without the use of variable names, as this would be closer to what is happening in your current implementation with `rpy2` as the data DataFrame and the fitted models are not bound to a variable name. This would give what follows (note: "closer" not "equal" - details about this would just distract from the main point):

```
stats::anova(lmer(formula='RT~cat1 + (1|ID)',
                  data=read.csv("http://chymera.eu/data/test/r_data.csv"),
                  REML=FALSE),
             lmer(formula='RT~cat2 + (1|ID)',
                  data=read.csv("http://chymera.eu/data/test/r_data.csv"),
                  REML=FALSE),
             lmer(formula='RT~cat2*cat1 + (1|ID)',
                  data=read.csv("http://chymera.eu/data/test/r_data.csv"),
                  REML=FALSE))
```

The outcome is an error in R.

```
Error in names(mods) <- sub("@env$", "", mNms) : 
  'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [3]
In addition: Warning message:
In anova.merMod(lmer(formula = "RT~cat1 + (1|ID)", data = read.csv("http://chymera.eu/data/test/r_data.csv"),  :
  failed to find unique model names, assigning generic names
```

What this suggests is that the R function `lme4:::anova.meMod` is making assumptions that can easily be violated, and the authors of the package should be notified.

It is also showing that expressions will be used to identify the model in the resulting text output.

The following is probably lacking a bit of elegance, but should be both a workaround and a way to keep labels for the models short.

```
# bind the DataFrame to an R symbol
robjects.globalenv['dataf'] = dfr
# build models, letting R fetch the symbol `dataf` when it is evaluating
# the parameters in the function call
res = list()
for formula in formulae:
    lme_res = lme4.lmer(formula=formula, data=base.as_symbol("dataf"), REML='false')
    res.append(lme_res)
# This is enough to work around the problem
compare = stats.anova(res[0], res[1], res[2])

# if not happy with the model names displayed by `compare`,
# globalenv can be filled further
names = list()
for i, value in enumerate(res):
    names.append('lme%i'  % i)
    robjects.globalenv[names[i]] = value 
# call `anova`
compare = stats.anova(*[base.as_symbol(x) for x in names])
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply! Sadly, however, your example yields a very similar error still. See [this updated notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/7396334/raw/84984a8e9ce39ec1275546fd3fb741ee2ac8d470/nlme-aov).

Comment: Ah. The issue comes from `data` being anonymous. Let me rewrite the answer.

Comment: In case you haven't seen this yet, this sparked [a discussion over on github](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/154). The bug is already closed, but won't fix my issue, ben bolker says he can't really reproduce this in RPy and I can't really reproduce it in pure R. Could you maybe help us out here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the `anova` method for `merMod` objects: it's essentially caused by the names of the objects being passed to R being too long, so that when `deparse()`d they end up being character vectors with (unexpectedly) more than one element.  This is fixed by https://github.com/lme4/lme4/commit/075c78d128db9d8398f43474621e49f32fdb5bd1 ; there is also now an (undocumented) argument `model.names` that can be specified to override the deparsing of model names.

You can install the development version using `devtools::install_github("lme4","lme4")`, otherwise you may have to wait a while for a patched version to be released ... can't think of a workaround other than structuring your call so that language objects that get passed to R are shorter when deparsed ...

Comment: I downloaded the version from github with devtols and I still get the exact same error. See my R sessionInfo here http://paste2.org/69HUmaZJ