# "list of length 2 not meaningful" when using anova

Tags: r, anova, lme4

I have two logistic regression models fitted with `lme4`.  I get an error when I try to use `anova` on them:

```
> class(tmp1)
[1] "glmerMod"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lme4"
> class(tmp2)
[1] "glmerMod"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lme4"
> anova(tmp1, tmp2)
Error in Ops.data.frame(data, data[[1]]) : 
  list of length 2 not meaningful
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928662/call-anova-on-lme4-lmer-output-via-rpy) reporting a similar error message, but according to the answers there that error seems to be due to passing a long expression as the argument to `anova`, which I'm not doing.

How can I run an anova on my models?